# Change enum column automatically

Tags: mysql

I have a column named `status` in a table which is of `enum` type and can have 2 values either `1` or `0`. I want to write a query which will automatically check the current value of Enum and change to the other value.

For example, I have rows in table:

```
id   |  name   |  status
-----+---------+---------
  1  |  Abc    |    0
-----+---------+---------
  2  |  xyz    |    1
```

Now I want to write a mysql query where I pass the `id` of row to update and I will automatically check the current status and change it to the other. For example, if I pass `id=1` it will automatically check the current value of status column and change it to `1`. Similarly, if I pass `id=2` it checks the status value of row 2 and changes it to `0`.

Comment: show some data and expected output !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `$id` is your *passed* id. Note, that while `bool` operations (like `status=!status`) is "nifty", it's not good to work with ENUM-s such way.

```
UPDATE t SET status=IF(status='0', '1', '0') WHERE id=$id
```

also, good idea would be to change type to `TINYINT` if it's about storing `0` and `1` only (then `status=!status` will be good idea to use)